# org-agenda column view: displaying abbreviated FILE property

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, column, filenames

I would like to display file names in my global TODO list in column view without directories and extensions.

`(setq org-columns-default-format "%TODO %FILE %ITEM")` followed by
<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> leads to something like

```
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL Available with ‘N r’: (0)[ALL]
(1)TODO (2)QUICK (3)WAITING (4)NEXT (5)STALL (6)DONE (7)CANCELLED  
TODO   | c:/Users/micha/Dropbox/org/175-stuff.org                      | * Todo 1
TODO   | c:/Users/micha/Dropbox/org/175-stuff.org                      | * Todo 2
TODO   | c:/Users/micha/Dropbox/org/175-stuff.org                      | * Todo 3
TODO   | c:/Users/micha/Dropbox/org/250-petcare.org                    | * Clean dog
```

I tried setting up a summarizer with

```
(setq org-columns-default-format "%TODO %FILE{filenamebase} %ITEM")

(defun summarize-file-name-base (values printf)
  (format (or printf "%s") (file-name-base (car values))))

(add-to-list 'org-columns-summary-types '("filenamebase" . summarize-file-name-base))
```

If I go back to the agenda list and refresh with <kbd>g</kbd> then go back to column mode with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> I get `org-entry-put: The FILE property cannot be set with ‘org-entry-put’`. If I remove the `file-name-base` call from the summarizer so that it just returns its input in the case of a list of a single string I don't get an error but I also get no change in formatting.

```
(defun summarize-file-name-base (values printf)
      (format (or printf "%s") (car values)))
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem but I have no idea how to fix it. I would suggest posting it to the org-mode ML.

Comment: Good idea. I'll do that after it falls off the front page on emacs.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```lisp
(defun my-column-display-value-transformer (column-title value)
  "Modifies the value to display in column view."
  (when (equal column-title "FILE")
    (file-name-base value)))

(setq org-columns-modify-value-for-display-function
      #'my-column-display-value-transformer)
```